# A whale of a nested riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

Each line has an answer. Each line's answers are clues for the paragraph's answer. Those in turn are clues for the section's final answer. The five final answers form a subjective list composed by me.

Partial answers are welcome.

**Number five**

> A side spin in pool or a man from Ross-on-Wye,
>   with rocket or mad; someone from TSRI,
>   the father of Jacob or writer of scifi.
>
> The flakes that keep floating around in the cold air,
>   the colour of what you find just outside Dover,
>   a melon, banana or lime or d'Anjou pear.
>
> With murder, extinction; a Catholic sermon,
>   a luminous square in the birthplace of Merman,
>   increase in velocity can be determined.

**Number four**

> *The Pianist* and *Chinatown* director's first name,
>   with Weimar or people's; most countries this form claim,
>   some twelve of these were understood by John Paul's brain.
>
> "What's up", a term used by a Bunny quite snidey,
>   profession of J. Jonah Jameson in *Spidey*,
>   creator of Windows, IT house now mighty.
>
> A stingy thing followed by golf exclamation,
>   the dominant degree in chordal progression,
>   between Mike and Oscar in NATO's expression.

**Number three**

> A city that always (some claim) is too windy,
>   a nightclub with theater, a place for a shindig,
>   the animals which are called Billy in Hindi.
>
> A German word meaning a cellar or basement,
>   the husband of Marge in prime-time entertainment,
>   with woman or one hit; a term of amazement.
>
> Deciduous trees used for *veniks* and *vihtas*,
>   the top-level domain for Indian tweeters,
>   the most-spoken Germanic tongue with Norse features.

**Number two**

> With path or star; something that sparkles or lustres,
>   the first name of Trinity and Leia's actors,
>   distress just loves company despite all factors.
>
> Both red and white ones are found inside the bloodstream,
>   the ink on one's skin used to illustrate some theme,
>   the pope's Swiss ones are a protective escort team.
>
> A little naïve girl who gets herself eaten,
>   in 2007 World Series unbeaten,
>   the world's tallest trees are found nowhere near Eton.

**Number one**

> An organ two of which you have close to your nose,
>   tall structure that's linked to no castles or châteaux,
>   through Oxford and Reading this waterway outflows.
>
> A term coined by More in his 1516 book,
>   what black is to white and what hook is to unhook,
>   with tense or bright; forecasts predicting its outlook.
>
> In contrast to alien, a.k.a. Earthling,
>   between quid and quo, or professional's shortening,
>   in *Genesis*; making of something from nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is clearly leading us to a list of

> movies, though what if anything they all have in common I am not confident about guessing. (E.g., I haven't spotted any awards they all won.) [EDITED to add:] What they have in common is that the person who made the puzzle likes them, and the title is just because it's a long puzzle.

Number five

```
A side spin in pool or a man from Ross-on-Wye,
with rocket or mad; someone from TSRI,
the father of Jacob or writer of scifi.
```

> english scientist isaac -> NEWTON

```
The flakes that keep floating around in the cold air,
the colour of what you find just outside Dover,
a melon, banana or lime or d'Anjou pear.
```

> snow white fruit -> APPLE

```
With murder, extinction; a Catholic sermon,
a luminous square in the birthplace of Merman,
increase in velocity can be determined.
```

> mass times acceleration -> FORCE

so I think this yields

> GRAVITY. (There's a recent movie of this title. It won some Oscars.)

Number four

```
The Pianist and Chinatown director's first name,
with Weimar or people's; most countries this form claim,
some twelve of these were understood by John Paul's brain.
```

> roman republic language -> LATIN

```
"What's up", a term used by a Bunny quite snidey,
profession of J. Jonah Jameson in Spidey,
creator of Windows, IT house now mighty.
```

> doc editor microsoft -> WORD

```
A stingy thing followed by golf exclamation,
the dominant degree in chordal progression,
between Mike and Oscar in NATO's expression.
```

> before fifth november -> REMEMBER (from the rhyme)

So this seems to be

> the movie MEMENTO.

Number three

```
A city that always (some claim) is too windy,
a nightclub with theater, a place for a shindig,
the animals which are called Billy in Hindi.
```

> chicago music-hall(?) cats -> MUSICAL?

```
A German word meaning a cellar or basement,
the husband of Marge in prime-time entertainment,
with woman or one hit; a term of amazement.
```

> keller homer wonder -> ER?

```
Deciduous trees used for veniks and vihtas,
the top-level domain for Indian tweeters,
the most-spoken Germanic tongue with Norse features.
```

> birch in swedish -> BJORK

Perhaps this leads us to

> DANCER IN THE DARK, a movie involving a medical operation whose soundtrack is by Björk. It won the Palme d'Or.

[EDITED to add:]

> It turns out that I was kinda lucky to get this one, because the second stanza is actually pointing to *blindness* (Helen Keller was of course blind and [the poet] Homer is said to have been ... and so was *Stevie* Wonder). D'oh!

Number two

```
With path or star; something that sparkles or lustres,
the first name of Trinity and Leia's actors,
distress just loves company despite all factors.
```

> shining carrie misery -> (STEPHEN?) KING

```
Both red and white ones are found inside the bloodstream,
the ink on one's skin used to illustrate some theme,
the pope's Swiss ones are a protective escort team.
```

> cell tattoo guard -> PRISON?

```
A little naïve girl who gets herself eaten,
in 2007 World Series unbeaten,
the world's tallest trees are found nowhere near Eton.
```

> red-riding-hood red-sox redwood -> RED

This might point towards

> THE SHAWSHANK REDEMPTION, a movie about a *prison* break based on a novel by *Stephen King* in which one character is nicknamed *Red*. It was nominated for some Oscars but didn't win any.

Number one

```
An organ two of which you have close to your nose,
tall structure that's linked to no castles or châteaux,
through Oxford and Reading this waterway outflows.
```

> eye tower thames -> LONDON

```
A term coined by More in his 1516 book,
what black is to white and what hook is to unhook,
with tense or bright; forecasts predicting its outlook.
```

> utopia opposite future -> DYSTOPIA?

```
In contrast to alien, a.k.a. Earthling,
between quid and quo, or professional's shortening,
in Genesis; making of something from nothing.
```

> human pro creation -> SEX?

Best I can do with this is

> Having tried out a number of dystopies set wholly or partly in London and featuring sex to some extent, it turns out that the intended one is CHILDREN OF MEN. Other candidates: Brave New World, Nineteen Eighty-Four, A Clockwork Orange. (There's also *The Iron Heel*, written by Jack London, but I don't think it was ever made into a movie.)

So the full list seems to be

> Children of Men; The Shawshank Redemption; Dancer in the Dark; Memento; Gravity.

*Credit where it's due*

> Shahriar Mahmud Sajid and Taleeb both informed me that cats are called "billy" in Hindi, which I had somehow failed to discover. El-Guest made a quite-possibly-correct suggestion for #1. Mohirly made an *actually* correct suggestion for #1. Chronocidal revealed that Pope JP2 knew 12 languages. Thanks, all!

Comment: for number 3 first paragraph- Rot13(Pngf ner pnyyrq ovyyl va uvaqv)

Comment: English for billy is cat

Comment: #2 and #5 correct!

Comment: #3 and #4 as well.

Comment: Could #1 be a London-set film based on a certain on-time, colourful novel by Burgess?

Comment: I guess it could be. Not all that much sex in that one either, so far as I can recall.

Comment: Your first guess is what I had initially thought when seeing the clues, but the movie versions of your two initial guesses are more “cult classics” possibly than your new guess. That was the most famous of the movies I found that fit the criteria, anyway.

Comment: Yes, I agree: given that we're looking for movies (which wasn't so clear when I first attacked that section) it seems very likely.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I’d imagine that the list is just @jafe’s top five favourites

Comment: Yes, that seems possible. But the title does seem like it calls for some sort of explanation...

Comment: Could #1 be rot13(puvyqera bs zra)?

Comment: Pope John Paul II knew & spoke Polish, Latin, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese, French, English, German, Ukrainian, Serbo-Croatian, Slovak and Esperanto

Comment: @Chronocidal Ohhhhh!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan This makes that entire answer `Ihytne, n svyz jevggra naq qverpgrq ol Oelna Wbuafba` (rot13)

Comment: Why? I think the answer I have there fits better .. especially as jafe has already said it's correct.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan The answer you have put can be split into 3 'types': "Early", "Classic" and "Vulgar"

Comment: True enough. But we need to use all three lines to get the movie name.

Comment: Also, I think Vulgar was specifically imperial rather than republican, chronologically.

Comment: @El-Guest is correct about how the list was selected. The title has no special meaning, it just refers to the size of the puzzle... The final paragraph refers to rot13[yvgreny onolznxvat, abg cebireovny] :)

Comment: If it’s yvgreny onolznxvat, then wouldn’t Gareth’s first answer make the most sense (because of the whole bottling thing in the story?)

Comment: @El-Guest Hmm, you're right. It seems that's a completely valid answer. (The one that I had in mind was found by Mohirl above)

Comment: I believe your "music-hall" could be "cabaret"?

Comment: And given the primary plot point for #1, you could argue that the appropriate 3rd answer is PREGNANCY or CHILDBEARING (or similar) instead of SEX.

Comment: Yup, indeed you could. I don't have much confidence guessing what the "canonical" answer is for either.

Comment: @feelinferrety I was going for "fertility" but obviously all of those are equally good (and the hint works with either one). Fwiw, the *German word* paragraph was intended to refer to a disability shared by those three people.

Comment: Oh! Stevie never occurred to me, and I didn't know he had that condition.

Answer (score 6):

**Extremely Partial Answer**

Number five

A side spin in pool or a man from Ross-on-Wye,

> ENGLISH

with rocket or mad; someone from TSRI,

> SCIENTIST

the father of Jacob or writer of scifi.

> ISAAC

So this refers to

> NEWTON.

The flakes that keep floating around in the cold air,

> SNOW

the colour of what you find just outside Dover,

> WHITE (as in White Cliffs of Dover, thanks @Stidgeon

a melon, banana or lime or d'Anjou pear.

> FRUIT

This refers to

> SNOW WHITE FRUIT: so APPLE (thanks, @Stidgeon!)

With murder, extinction; a Catholic sermon,

> MASS

a luminous square in the birthplace of Merman,

> FORCE?

increase in velocity can be determined.

> ACCELERATION

This refers to

> NEWTON’S SECOND LAW

Altogether...

> ??

Number four
The Pianist and Chinatown director's first name,

> ROMAN

with Weimar or people's; most countries this form claim,

> REPUBLIC

some twelve of these were understood by John Paul's brain.

> APOSTLES?

This refers to

> SAINT PETER?

"What's up", a term used by a Bunny quite snidey,

> BUGS

profession of J. Jonah Jameson in Spidey,

> EDITOR

creator of Windows, IT house now mighty.

> BILL? GATES?

This refers to

> 

A stingy thing followed by golf exclamation,

> Bee+fore = BEFORE

the dominant degree in chordal progression,

> FIFTH

between Mike and Oscar in NATO's expression.

> NOVEMBER

This refers to

> GUY FAWKES

Altogether:

> ??

Number three
A city that always (some claim) is too windy,

> CHICAGO

a nightclub with theater, a place for a shindig,

> 

the animals which are called Billy in Hindi.

> 

This refers to

> 

A German word meaning a cellar or basement,

> KELLER

the husband of Marge in prime-time entertainment,

> HOMER

with woman or one hit; a term of amazement.

> WONDER

This refers to

> HELEN

Deciduous trees used for veniks and vihtas,

> BIRCH

the top-level domain for Indian tweeters,

> IN

the most-spoken Germanic tongue with Norse features.

> DANISH

This refers to

> 

Altogether:

> 

Number two
With path or star; something that sparkles or lustres,

> 

the first name of Trinity and Leia's actors,

> CARRIE

distress just loves company despite all factors.

> MISERY

This refers to

> 

Both red and white ones are found inside the bloodstream,

> CELLS

the ink on one's skin used to illustrate some theme,

> TATTOO

the pope's Swiss ones are a protective escort team.

> GUARD

This refers to

> The MILITARY/POLICE?

A little naïve girl who gets herself eaten,

> 

in 2007 World Series unbeaten,

> BOSTON

the world's tallest trees are found nowhere near Eton.

> REDWOOD?

This refers to

> 

Altogether:

> 

Number one
An organ two of which you have close to your nose,

> EYES

tall structure that's linked to no castles or châteaux,

> TOWER

through Oxford and Reading this waterway outflows.

> THAMES

This refers to

> 

A term coined by More in his 1516 book,

> UTOPIA (thanks, @deep thought!)

what black is to white and what hook is to unhook,

> OPPOSITE

with tense or bright; forecasts predicting its outlook.

> FUTURE

This refers to

> DYSTOPIA, an opposite future Utopia.

In contrast to alien, a.k.a. Earthling,

> 

between quid and quo, or professional's shortening,

> PRO

in Genesis; making of something from nothing.

> EVE

This refers to

> 

Altogether:

> 

Comment: A few thoughts, r13(juvgr pyvssf bs qbire, uhzna cebperngvba, ybaqba rlr, gubznf zber - hgbcvn)

Comment: Number five, second paragraph: (ROT13) Juvgr pyvssf bs Qbire -> FABJ JUVGR SEHVG -> NCCYR

Comment: @deepthought: thanks very much! I’m not sure what the two middle references you were making  were for, but maybe I’m just tired!!

Comment: English for billy is cat

Comment: the animals which are called Billy in Hindi - is cat